# Why does ORDER BY command not print value in ascending order as it is by default in ascending?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am on a learning phase of SQL and I'm using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19. I was learning from Youtube, where the video states that the `ORDER BY` call by default sets the contents in ascending order.

But in my machine it is the other way around I also tried using the ASC and DESC calls.

[image]

I wanted the data to be arranged in ascending order i.e., count 2 and then count 3

Comment: Side note: `COUNT(Gender)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` if `Gender` is not nullable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you need to order by the count and not the gender.

```sql
...
ORDER BY COUNT(Gender) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another side note: calling the result column 'AgeCount' when it's actually a gender count (or gender-count-over-30, anyway) could be confusing, for yourself as well as others.